# Error php syntax error, unexpected 'case' (T_CASE)

Tags: php

Alguien sabe a que se puede deber este error en PHP? Este es el switch y da error en la linea que resaltare con una flecha

```
    switch(strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['type']))
{
        case 'audio/3ga': <---
        case 'audio/3gpp':
        case 'audio/3gpp2':
        case 'video/quicktime': //when recording on iOS devices the mov container is used. It contains AAC sound.
        case 'audio/mpeg'://in case of selecting an already existing recording
            break;
        default:
            die('{"s":0,"e":"Unsupported file type '.$_FILES['FileInput']['type'].'"}');
}
```

Comment: El error debe estar antes. Si copias ese código (_sin la flecha_) en un archivo independiente vas a poder ver que no tiene ningún error.

Comment: Estoy votando para cerrar esta pregunta como "no reproducible" porque no hay ningún error en el código. Prueba: http://rextester.com/JAQ27924

Answer (score -1, accepted):

utiliza comillas dobles, el switch lo estas haciendo en base a un String, por lo tanto si lo queremos comparar como string debemos usar comillas dobles, en vez de comillas simples, pues en algunos lenguajes de programacion (desconosco si este también), las comillas simples son utilizadas para caracteres no para strings.

Comment: Algo asi dices tu? case "audio/3ga":

Comment: No entiendo, Luis dice que use comillas dobles y tu que no se pueden usar comillas dobles, a que te refieres con debe ser por eso

Comment: él dice que no se deben utilizar comillas SIMPLES , ocupa comillas DOBLES en su lugar.

Comment: Luis, esto no es una respuesta. Menudo *dejavu* no? Si el problema es el que tu dices, esta pregunta se cerrará por No relacionado : Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico.

Comment: ok gracias por lo que dices, me estas enseñando muchas cosas hoy :) @lois6b

Comment: Espero que no te lo tomes a mal, no es nada personal. Hoy he reportado como 10 "respuestas", esto pasa mucho  . Y perdona si mis comentarios no son del todo politicamente correctos. Solo deseo la prosperidad del sitio. (y al aceptarte la respuesta, sin duda se cerrará)

Comment: que significa que se cerrará?

Comment: Cuando 5 personas votan para cerrar, la pregunta queda [en espera] durante unos dias (no recuerdo cuantos). Pasado ese tiempo se cierra y luego se puede votar para eliminar. Eso depende de si la respuesta que se hizo en el tiempo que estuvo abierta merece la pena. en este caso por el tipo de cierre, no es muy necesaria en el sitio. Visita META para mas informacion del sitio

Comment: ok y los puntos se descuentan?

Comment: No si no es eliminada. Se que tienes pocos y que cada punto es preciado pero si quieres un sitio mejor yo la borraría (una vez cerrada). Un saludo (nos estamos alargando con los comentarios. si quieres hablar estoy en el chat general )

Comment: @Luis ¿Cuál sería el problema de usar comillas simples? Por favor ¿podrías explicarlo en tu respuesta porque no lo entiendo? No veo el por qué de responder algo así, y menos si no está justificado. Además, ¿por qué motivo debería escapar la `/` si no es un caracter especial?

Comment: Luis y @Sergio1871 Les dejo un ejemplo que muestra que no hay ningún inconveniente en usar comillas simples http://rextester.com/JAQ27924

Comment: Es lo que andaba viendo, la he liado con el lenguaje ya que en java claramente no se puede pues son tipos diferentes, confusión mía y no pensar bien la respuesta, una disculpa, gracias por la corrección y borro mi comentario para que no haya problemas alguien que tenga la duda.